# list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: list, python-3.x

Trying to make one of my very first programs. Tried to convert to `int`, didn't work.

Getting this error:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

```
stations = ['Schagen', 'Heerhugowaard', 'Alkmaar', 'Castricum', 'Zaandam', 'Amsterdam', 'Sloterdijk', 'Amsterdam Centraal', 'Amsterdam Amstel', 'Utrecht Centraal', '’s-Hertogenbosch', 'Eindhoven', 'Weert', 'Roermond', 'Sittard', 'Maastricht']

IndEind = stations.index(eindStation)
IndBegin = stations.index(beginStation)

intBegin = int(IndBegin)
intEind = int(IndEind)

print('stations[0]: ', stations[intBegin, intEind])
```

Comment: I think this will work `print('stations[0]: ', stations[intBegin: intEind])`

Comment: can you give me an example of the output so that i can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `print('stations[0]: ', stations[intBegin: intEind])` instead of `print('stations[0]: ', stations[intBegin, intEind])` to understand in detail about Python's slice notation check this out : [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

For printing on separate lines give:

```
for i in stations[intBegin:intEind]:
    print(i)
```

Hope this helps.